# Angular-datatables server-side processing and Buttons extension. data is empty

Tags: angular-datatables

use Angular4 and angular-datatables.

Everything looks fine (pagination, column sorting, export buttons), but when I try to print/copy/export a table, it only outputs the headers, even though the rest of the data is there.

Any ideas what's should I check?

```
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 20,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
   this.service.getServerSidePaganated(dataTablesParameters).subscribe(resp => {
      that.cdrs = resp.data;
      callback({
        recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
        recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
        data: []
      });
    });
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'source' },
    { data: 'destination' },
    { data: 'dateTime'},
    { data: 'callTime'},
    { data: 'timeOnHold'},
    { data: 'disposition'},
    { data: 'recordingFileName'}
  ],
  // Declare the use of the extension in the dom parameter
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  // Configure the buttons
  buttons: [
     'print',
     'excel'
  ]
};
```

}

Comment: Same issue, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

you should set the callback data

```
 ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
   this.service.getServerSidePaganated(dataTablesParameters).subscribe(resp => {
   //   that.cdrs = resp.data;  // remove this line
      callback({
        recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
        recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
        data:  resp.data  // set data
      });
    });
```